Hexagonal lattice martingale

Would someone be able to check my answers for b) c)
For the brackets process $A_n$ I used $$A_n-A_{n-1} = \mathbb{E}\left(\left(Y_n-Y_{n-1}\right)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right)$$ and telescoped the result to find $A_n$.
My result was $A_n = \frac{n}{2}$.
And for c) i just used the fact that
$$\mathrm{E}\left[\langle Y\rangle_n\right]=\operatorname{Var}\left(Y_n-Y_0\right).$$
So the answer should also be $\frac{n}{2}$
I'm fairly sure i'm correct but i'd just like to check since these were both fairly easy to do for 10 mark questions.
